# Deciding between orderBy and orderByDescing Dynamicly in Linq To EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have A WishList Class , WishList Repository i want
to decide whether to use **OrderByDescending** or OrderBy based on a parameter
so i decided to write an extension methode as use it  follow

```
 var notWorkingResult = _wishListRepository.GetAll()
                                    .GroupBy(x => x.ProductId)
                                    .Select(w => new TestDTo
                                    {
                                       Items = w.xOrderBy(orderByParam).Select(x => x.AddedDate.ToString()).ToList()
                                    }).ToList();
```

and here is my extension method

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<Wishlist> xOrderBy(this IGrouping<Guid, Wishlist> source, string OrderBy)
{
    
        if (OrderBy == "asc") return (source.OrderBy(x => x.AddedDate));
        if (OrderBy == "desc") return (source.OrderByDescending(x => x.AddedDate));

        
       //default order by 
       return (source.OrderBy(x => x.AddedDate));
}
```

the problem is the breakpoints not event hit the method i get the error

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the
> method  'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[Data.Wishlist]  xOrderBy(System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Guid,Data.Wishlist],
> System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
> store expression

i would appreciate any workaround on this

Comment: I think its due to the fact that youre using `IGrouping<T, V>` rather than `IQueryable<IGrouping<T, V>>` thus you end up trying to evaluate a standard LINQ query rather than an EF IQueryable implementation.

Comment: What type is the `_wishListRepository`? Also the type of `Wishlist`?

Comment: @EfthymiosKalyviotis  _wishListRepository is IQuerable<Wishlist>

Comment: Also, maybe using an IComparer would be easier?

Comment: @EfthymiosKalyviotis how ? my mind is locked on this really. already a day on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) nuget package. Example:

```
myDataSource.OrderBy(columnName + " descending"); // for descending
myDataSource.OrderBy(columnName); // for ascending
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of an extension method, you can use the ternary operator:

```
Items = (orderByString == "desc" ? w.OrderByDescending(a => a.date) : w.OrderBy(a => a.date)).Select(x => x.AddedDate.ToString()).ToList()
```